# Loop backward in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I know this is going to be pretty basic, and will probably get down voted on this but I am kinda lost at the moment.

I have an array of objects

```
let data = [
  {id:1, Name: "Abe", RowNumber: 1 },
  {id:2, Name: "Bob", RowNumber: 2 },
  {id:3, Name: "Clair", RowNumber: 3 },
  {id:4, Name: "Don", RowNumber: 3.0 },
  {id:5, Name: "Edna", RowNumber: 3.1 },
  {id:6, Name: "Frank", RowNumber: 3.2 },
  {id:7, Name: "Gabe", RowNumber: 4 },
  {id:8, Name: "Helen", RowNumber: 5 },
  {id:9, Name: "Isabelle", RowNumber: 6 },
  {id:10, Name: "Jane", RowNumber: 7 },
  {id:11, Name: "Ken", RowNumber: 8 },
];
```

and I am trying to loop through them going backward and not forward, I have come up with this

```
for(let i = data.length; i != 0; i--){
    console.log(data[i].Name);
}
```

and that is not working, I get an error about Name being undefined.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: If you have an array `["a", "b", "c"]`, it has indexes `0`, `1`, and `2`. But it has length `3` - if you take `array[array.length]`, you'd get `undefined`. You start your iteration at `data.length`, which doesn't exist as an index.

Comment: Try `for(let i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(data[i].Name);
}`

Comment: @HereticMonkey it might, although the body of the mentioned question asks why does a code with incrementation work (EDIT: `@HereticMonkey` mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520074/looping-backwards-through-javascript-array-with-array-length-using-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let data = [
    { id: 1, Name: "Abe", RowNumber: 1 },
    { id: 2, Name: "Bob", RowNumber: 2 },
    { id: 3, Name: "Clair", RowNumber: 3 },
    { id: 4, Name: "Don", RowNumber: 3.0 },
    { id: 5, Name: "Edna", RowNumber: 3.1 },
    { id: 6, Name: "Frank", RowNumber: 3.2 },
    { id: 7, Name: "Gabe", RowNumber: 4 },
    { id: 8, Name: "Helen", RowNumber: 5 },
    { id: 9, Name: "Isabelle", RowNumber: 6 },
    { id: 10, Name: "Jane", RowNumber: 7 },
    { id: 11, Name: "Ken", RowNumber: 8 },
];
for (let i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(data[i].Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You iterate from `.length` to `1` inclusive. Apply a decrease by one someplace to iterate from `.length - 1` to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop from length minus one until zero.

This approach take the check and decrementing in one expression.

```js
let data = [
        { id: 1, Name: "Abe", RowNumber: 1 },
        { id: 2, Name: "Bob", RowNumber: 2 },
        { id: 3, Name: "Clair", RowNumber: 3 },
        { id: 4, Name: "Don", RowNumber: 3.0 },
        { id: 5, Name: "Edna", RowNumber: 3.1 },
        { id: 6, Name: "Frank", RowNumber: 3.2 },
        { id: 7, Name: "Gabe", RowNumber: 4 },
        { id: 8, Name: "Helen", RowNumber: 5 },
        { id: 9, Name: "Isabelle", RowNumber: 6 },
        { id: 10, Name: "Jane", RowNumber: 7 },
        { id: 11, Name: "Ken", RowNumber: 8 }],
    i = data.length;

while (i--) {
    console.log(data[i].Name);
}
```